# Need to put a script above </body> tag in header.php - WP 5.7.1

Tags: php, functions, tags, scripts, body-class

I need to put this script above the  tag in the header.php.

window.Futy = { key: '0000000000' };
(function (e, t) {
    var n = e.createElement(t);
    n.async = true;
    n.src = 'https://v1.widget.futy.io/js/futy-widget.js';
    var r = e.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
    r.parentNode.insertBefore(n, r);
})(document, 'script');

But with the new header.php and hooks and function.php I don't know how to do this.
I'm not a developer. So please tell me in a easy way as possible

Comment: above the </body> tag.

Comment: If you mean that you want to put the code in the `<head>` tag, than you need to hook into `wp_head` action

Comment: No, not in the <head> tag, but above the </body> tag

Comment: Oh, than you can use the `wp_footer` action

Comment: Okay, thanks. But I'm completely new with this kind of wp_footer actions, hooks, etc. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

As @Buttered_Toest mentioned, this snippet works well. 
(This code goes to functions.php)

```
function futy_widget_footer(){ ?>
    <script>
        window.Futy = { key: '0000000000' }; (function (e, t) { var n = e.createElement(t); n.async = true; n.src = 'https://v1.widget.futy.io/js/futy-widget.js'; var r = e.getElementsByTagName(t)[0]; r.parentNode.insertBefore(n, r); })(document, 'script'); 
    </script>
<?php } 

add_action('wp_footer','futy_widget_footer');
```